# Is WD PR4100 supports Seagate EXOS X18z ST18000NM009J?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, nas, cloud-storage, wd-pr4100

I'm using [My Cloud Pro Series PR4100](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/network-attached-storage/wd-my-cloud-pro-series-pr4100) as NAS storage.
I'm using [WD Red NAS Hard Drive 6TB](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-red-sata-hdd?sku=WD60EFAX)×4 HDD right now. I want to change them with [Exos™ X18](https://www.seagate.com/nl/nl/products/enterprise-drives/exos-x/x18/) 18TB×4.
Is it support?

Comment: Nothing in the manual states what drives are compatible, so you may have to reach out to http://support.wdc.com/